# AD с правами

Tags: active-directory, администрирование, windows-server

Доброго всем времени суток.

Вопрос по администрированию, создал я AD на сервере, теперь разруливаю права.
Есть у меня группа "students", в той группе их профиль с юзерскими правами, но как-то случилось, что им по предмету безопасности надо юзать профиль с АДМ-правами.

Вот как безопаснее всего выделить им эти права?

В AD, вроде, 4 административных профиля: простой, домена, схемы и предприятия.
Честно, я лишь про 2 профиля что-то понимаю (локальный и доменный), а про остальные ничего не знаю, чем они отличаются от других.  
Пасс от локального админа (на самой раб. станции) тоже давать не хочу.  
Как лучше поступить в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В идеале, я бы конечно посоветовал вам развернуть ещё 1 КД на виртуальной машине и подключил бы студенческие компьютеры в этот домен. Соответственно, внутри этого домена их можно поместить в группу Администраторов и не беспокоится по поводу основного домена. Добавлять пользователей в группу любых администраторов весьма опасно на основном КД. Потому что любая из этих 4 групп пользователей даёт достаточно много прав, что бы устроить вам настоящую головную боль.

Так же, рекомендую ознакомиться со статьей о группах пользователей на [msdn.microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc756898%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Честно про права администраторов так и думал, а создавать под 1-2 занятия в месяц вертуалку + на неё пропускать инет + поднимать на ней домен + ... +... Думаю студенты такой работы не оценят. Да и ни кто вообще не оценит.    
В данном случае удобнее уже просто виртуалку на каждый поставить. Пускай там и ковыряются.    
(P.S. Какой баран спрограммировал на Enter отправку сообщения здесь? - это к админам прожекта)

Comment: Почему вы не рассмотрите альтернативный домен для учебных классов на постоянной основе? Я думаю, это было бы вполне удобно при должном подходе. Не обязательно для этого брать даже Win. Можно посмотреть в сторону проекта Zential (ubuntu based).
http://www.zentyal.com/zentyal-server/